# How to intercept HTTP request header from the root URL that loads angular application

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular6, single-sign-on

I am working on an angular application that is integrated with a third party Single Sign On server. When we hit the application's root URL, it redirects to a SSO server, which then authenticates the user and redirects to the angular application. I need to fetch the logged-in user details that is encoded in the HTTP request header which is being sent from the SSO server to the Angular application. But the HTTP interceptor of the angular application doesn't intercept this request that loads the angular application. Can you please help me with this. (The application is developed using angular 6)

Comment: Show your [mcve] and any research you have done up to now. You might want to [edit] the question to make it clear what you want to do, and what you have tried and any results (including errors). The idea is that with more context someone might be able to suggest something you did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

If the http intercetpor you mentioned is the [interceptor from the Angular Http Client module](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses), you won't be able to do what you want this way (you can only intercept the requests/responses made within the Angular Http Client).
You will have to do it another way, maybe using cookies, if the SSO applications run under the same domain.